# What are mirrored characters? Which common ones exist?

Tags: kanji

I came across [this post](https://twitter.com/gyankotsu/status/1371666634981662723?s=10) on Twitter:

> ぎゃんこ
> @gyankotsu
> mirrored 死 from tokyo ghoul:re
>
> [image]

I don't really understand what `mirrored 死` refers to, and from the picture I'm still quite confused.

What are mirrored characters? Which common ones exist?

Comment: You draw a line down the middle and replace the right side with the mirrored left side, and voila! I believe this just shows the author's creativity, rather than something common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That large character next to オッガイ is a fictional "kanji" invented by the author of Tokyo Ghoul to write オッガイ in one character. It makes absolutely no sense outside the work. You cannot type this character using your PC or smartphone. Technically, it's a [*gaiji*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#Gaiji).

Obviously it was made by "mirroring" the left part of 死 ("death"), but it's not a common convention at all. In this information age, the invention of totally new fictional kanji is not common at all in the first place. This is nothing more than his unique wordplay on kanji.